# vscode: how to ignore system include path

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code

in my project, i use a Structure type both defined by the project header file(src/include/rpc/svc.h) and the system include path(e.g: /usr/include/rpc/svc.h)

when i want to see the struct define, the editor often jump to the system include path file, how to modify vscode settings so it can ignore the system include path, thanks

Comment: Same issue here.  My project has an include called profile.h  but Intellisense is finding /usr/include/profile.h instead.    Causes a cascade of annoying errors making Intellisense mostly useless in this project.

Answer (score -1):

ref: [Customizing default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp)

when you set

```
C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath : string[]
```

system include will ignore

string[] not null

Comment: This answer came from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp
But it makes no more sense there than it did here.    If anyone figures out how that works, to override the system include path, I very much need to know.  I have the same problem as the OP.